# Get all keys exists in NSDictionary and put into Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

[image]

When I snapshot from child "abc" I got this NSDictionary, "3c" can be added more nested childs. How can I get all the keys within an NSDictionary and put into Array
Expected result: ["abc","1a","2b","3c"]

value.allkeys just take same hierarchy keys

Comment: let allKeys = abc.keys

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Recursive function is nice approach to solve this kind issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AechoLiu writes a recursive approach is a nice way to go about it. Something like the below:

```
func nestedKeys(in dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [String] {
    guard let dictionaryValues = dictionary.values.filter({ $0 is [String: Any] }) as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return [String]() + dictionary.keys
    }
    let subKeys = dictionaryValues.reduce([String]()) { result, dictionary in
        return result + nestedKeys(in: dictionary)
    }
    return dictionary.keys + subKeys
}
```

The above expects your dictionaries to be of the format `[String: Any]` obviously.